# Streamlit adding IDs to Elements

Tags: python, streamlit

I currently have to work with python streamlit and I need to add an ID to an image, so that I can manipulate it later on with js and css. Streamlit doesnt support the option to add IDs in its elements like st.image.

I've tried working around this with using a `st.markdown("<div id='someID'>", unsafe_allow_html=True)` infront of the image but streamlit just closes this tag and puts it in another container.

Do you see any way to work around this?

Comment: Hey Anjo! Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: I have actually asked the same question on [this forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/assign-id-to-widget-html-block/26737)... There is a feature request already open for it: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/3888 (please give it a thumbsup!)

Comment: The only way how I was able to achieve what I wanted to do was by using custom streamlit components in which I wrote my own js code. As far as I did figure there aren't other good workaround to this...

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround that is using the names of the elements from inspect. The downside is that they continue to change if you make updates to the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).